# qs.parse read query param without decoding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get email from URL without decoding.

URL: https://localhost:3000/register/activate?token=JAItBAPArUSukXae0Q3J&email=kiran+39@gmail.com

Note: Due to some technical limitation I can not encode the URL. Since it's coming from a third party vendor.

Initial code:

```
var email = qs.parse(window.location.search, {
    ignoreQueryPrefix: true,
  }).email;
```

This works but when email has "+" sign it decodes it as " ". So, I am trying to replace spaces with "+" again with the below code. But I am having some issue with types. Can you please help me what's the best way to fix this.

Code:

```
  let email: string =
    qs.parse(window.location.search, {
      ignoreQueryPrefix: true,
    }).email || "";

  if (email) email.replace(/ /g, "+");
```

[image]

But I am getting a type **error**:

**Argument of type 'string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'**

Comment: You should address the root cause, i.e. you should encode your URL parameters, if you want symbols in URL parameters. Your example should be encoded as `https://localhost:3000/register/activate?token=JAItBAPArUSukXae0Q3J&email=kiran%2B39%40gmail.com` in the first place

Comment: @RickyMo Thanks for the suggestion. But due to some technical limitation I can not encode the URL. Since it's coming from a third party vendor.

Comment: File a bug with the vendor then because they're doing it wrong

Comment: @Phil thanks. I have already raised a ticket with them. And was trying to hack my way through it temporarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work-around for this is to pass a custom decoder to `qs.parse`, one that simply returns the string without decoding it

```js
const email = qs.parse(search, {
  ignoreQueryPrefix: true,
  decoder: s => s
}).email
```

[image: Edit dreamy-thunder-uwi9n]